# How to apply a operation on a subset of columns in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

Consider a example:

```
library(data.table)
myDt <- data.table(a=rep(1:10), b=paste(1:10, "000",sep=","), c=paste(2:11, "000", sep=",") )
myDt
```

Now I want to convert the character columns into numeric. Basically I want to remove the commas. I have already figured a way.

```
charToNumCols <- c("b", "c")

numColsDt <- myDt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x)) ), .SDcols=charToNumCols]

newDt <- data.table(myDt[, .SD, .SDcols=setdiff(names(myDt), charToNumCols)],     numColsDt)
```

Now I want a solution in which I dont have to create an intermediate data.table. Originally for this I wrote the following R code

```
myDt <- myDt[, charToNumCols:=lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x)) ), .SDcols=charToNumCols]
```

But this does not do the required operation.

Can anyone answer what should be the most efficient coding for the above, considering data.table in R?

Comment: `myDt[, (charToNumCols):=lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x)) ), .SDcols=charToNumCols]`

Comment: You do know that you don't need to use `<-` as well as `:=`, right?

Comment: Np, see @Amandas comment above and the linked question. No need to use `<-` when using `:=`.